# How to launch 100 and more servers in Chef

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, bootstrapping, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am new to chef. I have successfully configured chef workstation and server.

So by using this below command I am able to launch only one instance:

```
knife ec2 server create –image ami-cc5af9a5 -i ram.pem –flavor m1.small -x root –groups chef-client -Z us-east-1a -r “role[webserver]”
```

By this command I can bootstrap only one node:

```
knife ec2 server create –image ami-a4827dc9 -i NVirginia.pem –flavor t2.micro -x root –groups RC-Corporation -Z us-east-1a -r "role[learn_chef_httpd]"
```

I want to launch and Bootstrap 100+ instances, so how can I customize these commands?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to help.  Are you asking how to launch more than one instance with an identical configuration?  Use a `for` loop (although I suspect you will hit your instance limit in AWS if you haven't asked for an increase).  Are you asking how to create new cookbooks?  That's outside the scope of StackOverflow.  Asking for a tutorial isn't appropriate on Stack Overflow.  Try https://learn.chef.io/

Answer (score 0):

`knife-ec2` is aimed at relatively small scale interactive usage and is not intended for this. Look at tools like CloudFormation, SparkleFormation, and Terraform.